# Flutter Android - Write files to external storage

Tags: android, flutter, android-permissions, android-external-storage

I am unable to write a file to the external storage (e.g. `/storage/emulated/0/Example`).

My current configuration looks as follows:

- `targetSdk: 33`
- `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE added`
- `"storage" permission request at runtime (Permission.storage.request())`

With this configuration, I always get a `"permanently denied"` when checking the storage permission on runtime. Therefore I added the following to AndroidManifest:

- `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"`

With this change, I get a permission request window at runtime and I can confirm that my app can use this permission.

Now the permission check returns `"granted"`, but if I try to write a file e.g. `/storage/emulated/0/Example/test.txt` I get an error:

```
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = '/storage/emulated/0/Example/test.txt' (OS Error: Operation not permitted, errno = 1)
```

Then I tried it with the Granular Media Permissions for Android 13:

- `READ_MEDIA_IMAGES, READ_MEDIA_AUDIO, READ_MEDIA_VIDEO`

This also did not work for me.

The only way I got this working is by defining the `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission. But if I upload my appbundle Google rejects it because of this permission.

What other options do I have for this requirements:

- `Flutter`
- `targetSdk > 33`
- `allow user to save files to any folder he wants`
- `do not use MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create files or directories in root of external storage anymore.

Use one of the public directories like Documents, Download, DCIM, Pictures, ...

Comment: even if you are willing to ask the user for permission to do so? I think this is not fully accurate, although android does make it as hard as possible. I was able to write a single file, using https://alexrintt.io/shared-storage/Usage/Storage%20Access%20Framework/#opendocumenttree (but am giving up on getting actual file path access)